# When do I need move-operations , c++

Tags: c++, pointers, move

Imagine the following code

```
 struct Vehicle { virtual void drive() = 0; };
 struct Car: public Vehicle { 
   void drive() override { std::cout <<   "driving a car\r\n"; } 
 };
 struct Cycle : public Vehicle { 
   void drive() override { std::cout << "driving a cycle\r\n"; } 
 };
 Vehicle* makeVehicle(const std::string& type) {
   if (type == "car") { return new Car(); } 
   else if (type == "cycle") { return new Cycle(); } 
   else { return nullptr; } 
 }
```

Do I need do implement moving-operations concerning "return new Car()"? Or are they senseless because of the use of pointers?
In which cases are the default moving-operation sufficient?

Cheers!

Comment: Please post actual code, not images.

Comment: You are returning a pointer, so there will be no move operation for the object

Comment: Read about `return value optimization`. You shouldn't move values you return. The book `Effective Modern C++` also covers the topic of moving and forwarding quite nicely.

Comment: If you are using "new" in modern C++ you are probably making a mistake. (If you understand why I make this comment, you'll also understand where the exceptions are).

Comment: but in which cases I have to implement a move construct and when I can use the default?

Answer (score 3):

If you have move, you have C++11, and if you have C++11, you have `unique_ptr`. So you actually want to write your code like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Vehicle> makeVehicle(const std::string& type {
    if (type == "car") { return std::make_unique<Car>(); }
    ...
}
```

`unique_ptr` indicates that the person calling `makeVehicle` now owns the returned object and will automatically ensure that it gets destroyed and memory returned. `unique_ptr` implements move operations automatically, that's why this code can compile (if it wasn't movable or copyable, it wouldn't be possible to return it from a function).

So basically, for polymorphic types, typically you will not need to implement moving operations. But `unique_ptr` doesn't provide copying operations so you still may want to implement the oldie-but-goldie `clone` function (if you really need it).

I recommend reading more about move semantics and in particular the "Rule of Zero"; it's generally better to avoid implementing copy/move by hand where possible. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three.

Comment: @mcAngular2 important to read and understand: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three Let me give you the gist: **Rule of three**: "If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three." **Rule of zero**: you require one of the three far less than you might expect (almost never). So in conclusion you (almost) always are in the situation where you must not declare any of them.

Comment: @bolov I will add the link from your comment to the answer, if that is alright.

Comment: sure, 5$ per word :) obviously I am joking. It's just a comment, feel free to add it in the question.

Comment: but in which cases I have do implement a move construct and when I can use the default?

Comment: @mcAngular2 I don't really know what kind of answer you are expecting. You have to implement it, if the default doesn't work for you, and that's basically it. Since the default move is to move members, you should try to pick members such that the default does work. There is no blanket answer other than to understand what is going on and and judge each case.

Comment: To give you an example of picking the right members: `std::mutex` is not movable, or copyable. Suppose you have a class that needs a `mutex` as a member. Uncopyable classes aren't such a big deal but immovable classes are quite annoying. A simple way to get moves without having to write them, is to simply use `unique_ptr<mutex>` as your member variable, instead of `mutex` directly. `unique_ptr<T>` is always movable regardless of what `T` is. Hope that helps.